# How to use CSLA FieldDataManager to track individual property IsDirty status?

Tags: csla

In a WinForms application I want to track the IsDirty status of a specific property (besides the IsDirty status of the business object. I found some references to Csla.Core.FieldManager.FieldDataManager being able to do this via its IsFieldDirty method, but I can not find an example.

In Visual Studio Intellisense does not show which parameters are needed in the FieldDataManager's constructor. I just get errors that there is no constructor with x arguments (tested with 0 up to 4 arguments).

FieldDataManager isn't mentioned in the CSLA books.
How can I use FieldDataManager to track the IsDirty status of a property?
Is there another way to do it?

Regards,
George